# Playlist of videos loaded in memory with PATH server

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I have a table where the path of the videos uploaded to the server is saved (I can change to BYTE saved if necessary), I can't put these videos in a loop autoplay list.

I need to download videos from a server, to have them in MEMORY, and to be able to play them automatically in a LOOP, I did this for WPF with VLC libraries, but I can't find an example to do it on the WEB, currently I use BLAZOR SERVER technologies, with ASP.NET core for the backend, you can combine native html code with BLAZOR

Any help, comment or suggestion would be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: The question is unclear and frankly, contains no information. To play video in the browser you need the [<video> tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) or a video player component. Either of them will use a `src` attribute that points to the source of the video. This can be a controller action or HTTP endpoint, anything that accepts a GET request and returns the video stream. It doesn't matter if the server is ASP.NET Core, Blazor Server (which is the same thing), Node, whatever. The video is played by the browser

Comment: The [Blazored Video](https://github.com/Blazored/Video) component wraps a `video` tag as a Blazor component and allows handling events through C#

Comment: It is hard to know how to help you. Provide examples of what you've done so far perhaps?

otherwiese @PanagiotisKanavos seems to give you some good clues.